# What is the meaning of Past participle in English sentence?

Tags: past-participles

What is the meaning of past participle verb in the English sentences.

a) Does it mean past action?

I have/had **seen** that movie. (Movie was seen in the past)

b) Does it mean **completed** action?

This is/was **broken** window ( Already broken window)

c) future status?

You will be **killed** by him. ( future possible but completed action )

I am expecting exact meaning of Past participle in English sentence. I am aware that it is used for passive voice, perfect tenses and as an adjective.

If my understandings are correct what will below sentence mean.

**All festivals are celebrated in our country.**

What is the meaning of **Celebrated** in above sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The Past Participle has no particular meaning of its own. It is used in several different constructions which have different meanings.

1. It is used after *have* (*has*, *had*, *haven't*, *hasn't*, *hadn't*) to form **perfect** constructions, which refer to past actions with present relevance. The exact meaning of this "present relevance" can vary - it might mean that the action is continuing to the present; or that it has finished very recently; or that its effects or results are still salient. Examples:

> I **have seen** her.
>
> We **hadn't left** yet (when something happened)

1. a) It is used after *to have* to form a past infinitive. (I list this separately from 1 because this use does not necessarily have a specifically "perfect" meaning):

> We hope **to have finished** by 10.

2. For transitive verbs, it is used with *be* (*am*, *are*, *is*, *were*, *was*, *being*, *been*) to form **passive** constructions. These can be in any tense, depending on the part of *be* used:

> Cars **are built** in that factory.
>
> With that microphone, you **will be heard**.
>
> The game **was stopped** when a cow ran onto the pitch.
>
> The cakes **had** all **been eaten**.
>
> The boxes **are being packed** right now.

2. a) Colloquially, we sometimes use part of *get* instead of part of *be* for the passive:

> The cakes **got eaten**.

3. For many verbs, it can be used as an adjective. The precise meaning varies, but is usually about the result of the corresponding verb. It can be used predicatively:

> The meat is **cooked**.

or attributively:

> They brought out the **cooked** meat.

Sometimes it is difficult to determine whether a past participle is being used as a passive or adjectivally. It is usually the tense that tells us. In the example above,

> The meat is cooked.

could be passive, but if it is, it is a simple present, which generally refers to a timeless or habitual condition. So if we were talking about a factory making pies, for example, where they cook meat every day, we might say *the meat is cooked in these ovens, and then transferred here to be placed in the pies*.

But if we were talking about a particular piece of meat, that would be odd in that meaning, because we usually express activities happening at this moment by a continuous construction, so we would say *The meat is being cooked*.

So in this context, *The meat is cooked* is much more likely to be interpreted as an adjective: *The condition of this piece of meat is that it is cooked, rather than raw, or frozen, or half-cooked*.